# Where is the following sequence convergent/absolute convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I have the following sequence:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\tan \frac{x}{2^n}$

Any idea how to decide this question? It is obvious that $x^n$ goes to infinity if $|x|>1$, but how does the $\tan \frac{x}{2^n}$ influence the sum? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: What is $\tan u$ approximately, when $u\to0$?

Comment: Then $tan u$ goes to 0 too right?

Comment: Yes but how? Like $u$, $u^2$, $3u^4$, other?

Comment: I guess that the $2^n$ is the main deciding factor, since $n$ goes to $\infty$

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoter explained his vote.

Comment: @Derenge Sorry but I do not know what to make of your last comment. What do you call "the main deciding facor" exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume first that $x \geq 0$. In general, we have that $\lim \limits _{y \to 0} \frac {\tan y} y = 1$. Since $\frac x {2^n} \to 0$, we have $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {\tan \frac x {2^n}} {\frac x {2^n}} = 1$, so by the limit comparison test your series has the same nature as $\sum x^n \frac x {2^n}$, which obviously has the same nature as $\sum (\frac x 2)^n$, which is a geometric series, and this is known to converge when its ratio is between $-1$ and $1$, which in your case means $0 \leq x < 2$.

If $x<0$, since $\tan$ is an odd function, your series can be rewritten as $\sum (-1)^{n+1} |x|^n \tan \frac {|x|} {2^n}$. If $-2 <x <0$, then $|x|^n \tan \frac {|x|} {2^n}$ decreases to $0$ (show that!), so by the Leibniz test your series is convergent. If $x \leq -2$, then $|x|^n \tan \frac {|x|} {2^n}$ cannot tend to $0$ so by the zero test the series must be divergent.

So, your series converges only for $|x|<2$.

In order to study the absolute convergece, place a modulus inside the series and you'll get $\sum |x|^n \tan \frac {|x|} {2^n}$, which can be studied as above with the limit comparison test, giving the same interval: $x \in (-2,2)$.

Comment: Very nice, but is this only the simple covergence or the absolute convergence too?

Comment: You edited it, thanks! :)

Comment: @Derenge: See my edit.

Comment: I accepted it, thanks for your effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=x^n \tan \frac{x}{2^n}.$ Consider $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|x|\dfrac{\tan \frac{x}{2^{n+1}}}{\tan \frac{x}{2^n}}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|x|\dfrac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}=\dfrac{|x|}{2}$$ When $x=2$ our $a_n=2^n\tan\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}\to2\not=0$